# how to configure eviction policy like LFU and LRU in jcache

Tags: redis, jcache, redisson

I want to set LFU eviction policy for redis. 
how to configure eviction policy like LFU and LRU with the help of jcache API or redisson API?

Answer (score 0):

You could not configure eviction policy via APIs; The only way is to edit the `maxmemory-policy` directive in redis conf file